# How to triangulate from a Voronoï diagram?

Tags: delaunay, voronoi

I computed a Voronoï diagram from a set of point (with [Boost.polygon](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/polygon/doc/voronoi_diagram.htm)).

I try to find a Delaunay triangulation, connecting each cell center for each Voronoï edge, but I miss some edges.

In the following image, the red dots are my initial points, the blue lines are the Voronoï edges (I ignored infinite edges), and the green lines are the triangulation edges (on green edge for each blue edge, connecting two cell origins).

We can see that diagonal edges are missing. What am I missing?

[image: voronoi diagram]

Comment: For future visitors, [this has been cross-posted on Computer Graphics SE](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/1815/16) where it has another answer (which I do not intend to copy over).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 Delaunay vertices lie on a common circle, this is a degenerate situation. Shift the points a little and you will recognize the problem.